# Counting sets and adding an element

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $A$ be a set with $n$ elements, where $n \in \mathbb{\omega}$. Suppose $s \notin A$, prove that $A \cup \{s\}$ has $n+1$ elements.

Here is what I have done so far:

By induction, let $P(n):$ if $A$ has $n$ elements, then $A \cup \{s\}$ has $n+1$ elements.

Base Case: ($n=0$) Notice that when $n=0$, there exists a bijection from $s$ to $\{1\}$, so the set $A \cup \{s\}$ has $n+1$ elements.  Therefore P(0) is true.

Inductive step: Suppose $P(n)$ is true for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  We want to show that $P(n+1)$ is true.  So suppose $s \notin A$ and $A$ has n elements. Then there exists a bijection $f:A \to \{1,2,...,n\}$ and there exists a bijection $g:{s} \to \{n+1\}$.  So let h be a bijection $h:A \cup \{s\} \to \{1,2,...,n,n+1\}$ then the set $A \cup \{s\}$ has $n+1$ elements.  So $P(n+1)$ is true.

Therefore, by induction, P(n) is true for all $n \in \mathbb{\omega}$

However, I'm not even sure induction is the right way to go about this, it doesn't feel totally right.  Thank you to anyone who helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof hasn't actually proved $P(n+1)$. To do that, you have to show that if $A$ has $n+1$ elements then if $s\notin A$ then $A\cup\{s\}$ has $n+2$ elements.

I don't think induction is necessary for this proof.

If $A$ has $n$ elements, then there is a bijection $f:A\rightarrow\{1,2,...,n\}$. For $s\notin A$, you can construct a bijection $h:A\cup\{s\}\rightarrow\{1,2,...,n+1\}$ by letting $h(a)=f(a)$ for $a\in A$ and $h(s)=n+1$.

You should show that this is a bijection, but using the fact that $f$ is makes this easy and you're done.